# Bootstrap table data with fixed width

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a table where the table data has a fixed width, since using the bootstrap classes, the columns expand depending on the text, and to avoid this the word-wrap is used with a fixed table layout..https://jsfiddle.net/3q7a3h1q/1/

```
<code></code>
```

from the fiddle above when i resize the browser the text overlaps on each other..how can i get the text not to overlap against each other

Answer (score 0):

Set 'minimum-width' for table and donot adjust column width.

Try this in your html,

```html
<table class="table table-borderless table-hover" style="min-width:500px">
```

Comment: It is `min-width` not minimum-width.

Comment: Thanks...its a typo anyway

Answer (score 0):

Add the below css. It will solve your issue.

```
table tr td:first-child{
   white-space: pre-line !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Now check, It is resolved. You added the `table-responsive` class to `table` element.
```

[Here is your fiddle solution revised :https://jsfiddle.net/3q7a3h1q/2/](https://jsfiddle.net/3q7a3h1q/2/)

Comment: but i want the table to be horizontally scrollable for mobile devices so it looks neat and uniform

Comment: ok. then add `overflow-x: auto` in your css and apply to table

Comment: thankyou..your code helped me, but it would be great if the table is horizontally scrollable still keeping the text intact without overlapping on one each other

Answer (score 0):

```
table {
  width:100%;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  table-layout: fixed;
}


td{
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

check this out...

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.